# make functions in the prerequisites

Tags: makefile

I'm in the process of learning `make` and am getting stuck on whether it is possible to use functions in the prereq's list for a target. Say I have the following...

```
FILES = folder1/file folder2/file folder3/file

$(FILES) : code/my_script.bash $(subst folder,dir,$@)
    bash code/my_script.bash $(subst folder,dir,$@)
```

In this case my_script.bash will run, even if folder1/file does not exist. I would anticipate that it would execute another rule to build that target first. When I replace the `bash` line with `echo $^`, all that is outputted is `code/myscript.bash`. It doesn't seem to be doing the replacement on `$@` to build the prereq. I see now that I can get the desired goal by using `%` in the target and prereq, but is it possible to use a function in the prereqs?

Comment: You can use functions but you *cannot* use target specific variables (like `$@`) without also using secondary expansion.

Comment: So `$$(subst folder,dir,$@)` should work as a prereq?

Comment: Do you want every output file to depend on *all* the input files? Or map one-to-one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use functions that depend on the target of the rule, you need to enable secondary expansion. To enable secondary expansion you need to use [`.SECONDEXPANSION:`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) besides doubling your `$` in the depdnencies. So:

```
FILES = folder1/file folder2/file folder3/file

all: $(FILES)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(FILES): code/my_script.bash $$(subst folder,dir,$$@)
    bash code/my_script.bash $(subst folder,dir,$@)
```

What the doubling of the `$` does is prevent the code from being evaluated during the first expansion.

You do not need secondary expansion if the functions you use in your prerequisites do not depend on variable that exist only when the rule is being evaluated (like `$@`).

Answer (score 0):

```
FILES = folder1/file folder2/file folder3/file    

$(FILES) : code/my_script.bash $$(subst folder,dir,$$@)
    bash code/my_script.bash $(subst folder,dir,$@)
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @JTG This is a complete answer (of a sort).

Comment: Ah, thank you @EtanReisner, I saw it in a queue and didn't notice the changes.  Still PDSchloss, you should include a description or explanation for this to be helpful to others.